# how to change add to cart button in opencart that works on firefox and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, button, opencart, shopping-cart

I have been struggling to fix this problem where I can't seem to get around the add to cart button not working in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Here is the code:

```
<file name="catalog/controller/module/featured.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[
        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        $data['text_read_more'] = $this->language->get('text_read_more');
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file name="catalog/language/english/module/featured.php">                 
    <operation>                         
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[                        
        // Text                       
        ]]></search>                         
        <add><![CDATA[                         
        $_['text_read_more'] = 'View Product';                        
        ]]></add>                 
    </operation>         
</file>

<file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/module/featured.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[            
        <button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        <button type="button"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $text_read_more; ?></span></a></button>          
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Comment: I almost peed my pants :-D *Internet explorer* - haven't heard that word for almost two years!!! ROFL!!! Anyway, your code is replacing the **add to cart** button with a link to the product detail... Did you write the code or was it within some 3rd party extension?

Comment: well I had to put that into consideration since I have to make sure it works on all browsers. But yes it's a third party extension.  But its basically the same thing what i wanted to do anyways i tried to manually change the code myself but same result. Is there a way the <button> can link to a href? without using php coding?